# How to understand "And from this it follows that where we meet resistance" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

> Your point about wizard dominance being FOR THE MUGGLES' OWN GOOD - this, I think, is the crucial point. Yes, we have been given power and, yes, that power gives us the right to rule, but it also gives us responsibilities over the ruled. We must stress this point, it will be the foundation stone upon which we build. Where we are opposed, as we surely will be, this must be the basis of all our counter-arguments. We seize control FOR THE GREATER GOOD. **And from this it follows that where we meet resistance**, we must use only the force that is necessary and no more. (This was your mistake at Durmstrang! But I do not complain, because if you had not been expelled, we would never have met.)
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I don't quite get "And from this it follows that where we meet resistance". It seems that there is no conjunction to link the two clauses: "*And from this it follows that where we meet resistance*", "*we must use only the force that is necessary and no more*".

How should we understand the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see where you have trouble parsing this sentence. Try this:

> And from this it follows that [where we meet resistance, we must use only the force that is necessary and no more.]

Here the lines echo a Spider Man quote: "[*with great power comes great responsibility*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/With_great_power_comes_great_responsibility)". And that is what *"this"* refers to in "from *this*". So basically the line in question means:

> Because we have to seize control for the greater good, where/when we meet resistance we must uses only the force that is necessary and refrain from excessive use of force.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the sentence could be made more clear. What it means is

> From this it follows that we must use no more force than is needed to overcome any resistance we may encounter.

The sentence given would be helped by a comma before "where." Such a comma would show that the clause starting with "where" and ending with "resistance" is a parenthetical further qualifying the injunction to use only minimal force.